# Verifying a C# string as a valid XML Schema anyURI

Tags: c#, parsing, xsd

Is there a better way to verify that a C# string is a valid xs:anyURI than the following?

```
public bool VerifyAnyURI(string anyUriValue)
{ 
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        SoapAnyUri anyUri = new SoapAnyUri(anyUriValue);
        result = true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    return result;
}
```

This constructor doesn't appear to throw any kind of exception. Is any valid string technically a valid anyURI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the `SoapAnyUri` constructor with Reflector, it doesn't perform any validation at all.

The **`anyURI`** data type [is defined as follows](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#anyURI):

> [Definition:]   anyURI represents a Uniform Resource Identifier Reference (URI). An anyURI value can be absolute or relative, and may have an optional fragment identifier (i.e., it may be a URI Reference). This type should be used to specify the intention that the value fulfills the role of a URI as defined by [RFC 2396], as amended by [RFC 2732].

So you can simply use **[`Uri.TryCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572.aspx)** with `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute` to verify that a string represents a valid value:

```
Uri uri;
bool valid = Uri.TryCreate(anyUriValue, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uri);
```